# Calling a Python function from multiple threads in C++

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

Found several similar threads, but nothing that would help me.

Basically, I have a C++ application, that wants to call a function from a Python script. This all works very well.

But because I need it to work somewhat in real-time and the python-function takes a bit long, I wanted to add multithreading.

Basically, one of the two scenarios:

1. A thread-pool in C++, where each thread will call the Python-function.

or

2. A thread-pool in Python, and C++ app is adding tasks into a Python-queue.

I kinda like the first option a bit more, so let's go with that. Basically, I have a python script with a function (actually, there's a Tensorflow prediction):

```
import time
def pfoo(msg):
  print("Python >> Function called)
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Python << Function finished)
```

And a C++ threadpool (mostly taken from [here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool)):

```
ThreadPool pool(4);

// initialize the Python
Py_Initialize();
// initialize thread support
PyEval_InitThreads();

// ...

PyObject* m_PyModule = PyImport_ImportModule( "test" );

PyObject* m_PyDict = PyModule_GetDict( m_PyModule );

PyObject* m_PyFoo = PyDict_GetItemString( m_PyDict, "pfoo" );

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { 

    pool.enqueue( [&] { 

      PyEval_CallObject( m_PyFoo, Py_BuildValue( "(s)", arg ) );

    } );
}
```

As you can imagine, nothing happens, because you can't just call the same function while it's still running.
I tried the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` macros, I tried the `PyGILState_Ensure()` thing and [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3641) more complex option. I'm out of ideas.

A tried the second scenario, where I have an infinite loop thread in Python, that reads tasks from a `queue.Queue()` and puts them into a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and the C++ app calls a function to add a task into the aforementioned queue. Doesn't work for me either (works if I just run it in Python, but doesn't work if embedded into C++).

Comment: Would it be OK for you if each thread ran a separate Python interpreter, and could call the same function but they could not interact with each other?  How about just using multiprocessing in Python?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I thought about it, but since I need to load a Tensorflow model and allocate several Gigabytes of GPU-memory to use it, this might turn problematic very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found a passable solution. Works with a synthetic example, but will require a live test with the Tensorflow prediction:

The python script still uses a threadpool, but no infinite thread-loop:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import time

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
lock = threading.Lock()
counter = 0

def worker(msg, n):
  global counter

  with lock:
    counter += 1

  print("Python >> Function called with (%s, %d)" % (msg, n))

  for i in range(n): # do some work...
    print("\tPython :: %s: %d" % (msg, i))
    time.sleep(1)

  print("Python << Finished function for (%s, %d)" % (msg, n))

  with lock:
    counter -= 1
    if counter < 0:
      counter = 0


def add(msg, n):
  global executor, counter
  if counter < 4:
    print("++%d threads are free, adding task: %s" % (4 - counter, msg))
    executor.submit(worker, msg, n)
```

And the C++ app simply calls the "add" function when necessary:

```
std::map<std::string, PyObject*> m_PyFunctions;

m_PyFunctions["add"] = PyDict_GetItemString( m_PyDict, "add" );

for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) 
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 100 ) );

    PyEval_CallObject( m_PyFunctions["add"], 
                       Py_BuildValue( "(s, l)", "task_#" + std::to_string( i ), std::rand() % 5 ) );
}
```

**EDIT**: yes, tested this with my main application, it works fine. A crude solution, but passable nonetheless.

Comment: Where do you acquire the Python GIL in your C++ code?  I think you need to, or your code may crash.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't... which is the weird part.

Comment: @JohnZwinck not sure about CPU utilization in this synthetic example, but adding two simple lines of code to output the current **thread_id** definitely shows, that the thread-pool works and tasks are being simultaneously executed in different threads. The main code is actually a machine-learning (prediction) task that is being run on GPU.

Comment: Very interesting example! Which Python do you use? I tried with Python 2.7 and it seems that threads are active only during  add(msg, n) call. Other words, if I add a delay to the abovementioned function I start seeing   "Python :: task_#..." just during that time...

Comment: @ArtemBobritsky that was Python 3.6, if memory serves...